# Why does git ls-files ignore the working directory when used in a git alias?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-alias, git-ls-files

I have a git repository with a few files and subdirectories.
If I have a terminal window open in one of these subdirectories and execute `git ls-files`, I get a list of the files within my current working directory. If I create the following alias and run it in the same directory:

```
[alias]
    lsAlias = "!f () { params=($GIT_PREFIX); cd \"${params[0]}\"; /home/user/some-script.sh; }; f"
```

`some-script.sh` calls `pwd` and `git ls-files`. `pwd` Correctly reports the current directory as expected, but `git ls-files` is behaving as if I am calling the command from the root of the git repository. If I adjust the alias to cut out the shell script:

```
[alias]
    lsAlias = "!f () { params=($GIT_PREFIX); cd \"${params[0]}\"; pwd; git ls-files; }; f"
```

I get the same behavior.

Here is the transcript of the second alias:

```
+ f
+ params=($GIT_PREFIX)
+ cd TestApp/Training/
+ pwd
+ git ls-files
```

This is running in git-bash on Windows 10.

**How do I have `git ls-files` respect the current working directory?**

Comment: Add `set -x;` at the front of the alias to log execution, and add the transcript to the question.

Comment: Mind, in general, `params=($GIT_PREFIX)` has a lot of undefined behavior in it, so I'd typically suggest avoiding it. See [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) -- and it only has the behavior described there if it's actually executed _with bash_. git aliases use `/bin/sh`, not bash, not bash, so array support isn't there at all.

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming you're on a distro where `/bin/sh` is provided by bash -- somewhere it was dash or ash you'd have a more explicit error from that code.

Comment: Anyhow -- `declare -p "${!GIT_@}" >&2` to list the environment variables named starting with `GIT_` set during the alias's execution. One of the results listed there will be responsible for the difference in behavior, so you can reverse that behavior change with an appropriate `unset`.

Comment: BTW, on MacOS with git 2.42.0, I can't reproduce the stated behavior -- I get `ls-files` output local to the cwd, not the repository root.